# Making Google Driveas storage in my website

Tags: php, html, google-drive-api

I just want to ask a question about Google Drive. Can I make it a storage, for example? All I really want is this:

- I want to upload a file in google drive name Image1.jpg from my website using upload image and stored it in google drive folder.
- After I uploaded it in Google Drive, I want it to display in my website as my products.

I want actually to have dynamic uploading images and after uploading, a script to automatically display it in my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to check out the Google Drive API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

Note that this will require authentication into your drive account.

In order to upload files from your website to Drive, see:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

In order to display files from Drive on your website, you can write a script to download files from drive to the server you are hosting your site from, and then render it on your web page. To download from Drive, see:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: sir, can i make a script or php code for the authentication of my google drive ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to implement the Oauth2 flow to get a "refresh token". Once you have a refresh token once, you can repeatedly use it to get an "access_token". This access_token will be passed into the Drive APIs. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2. If you only need this for your account, you can retrieve the token from the Google APIs dashboard.

Comment: the token means requires login sir ?

Comment: Yes, when you go through the oauth2 flow, one of the requests will return a link to a portal where you can authenticate. You only need to authenticate once to get your refresh token.

Comment: sir last question, can u provide me some javascript that serves as a token ? i am using php

Comment: This page has template code for JavaScript: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication